# Calling a __str__ in python

Tags: python, string, class

Ive been struggling with an assignment. I'm calling the `str` method located in subclass Triangle from the class ShapeSet(I've highlighted relevant codesnippets). I can't get the proper string output when I'm calling it this way(calling it directly, print(triangle), works totally fine).

When calling the `str` method from class ShapeSet:

```
<method-wrapper 'str' of list object at 0x011E13C8>
```

When calling directly:

```
>>>print(triangle):
Type:Triangle, base:3, height:4
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Shape(object):

    def area(self):
        raise AttributeException("Subclasses should override this method.")

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        self.base=base
        self.height=height
    def area(self):
        self.area=(self.base*self.height)/2
        return self.area
    def __str__(self):
        return "Type:{}, base:{}, height:{}".format(self.__class__.__name__,                             self.base, self.height)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(other)==Triangle and self.base==other.base and self.height==other.height


class ShapeSet:
    def __init__(self):
         self.shape_dict={}

    def addShape(self, sh): 
        try:
            self.shape_dict[type(sh)].append(sh)
        except KeyError:
            self.shape_dict[type(sh)]=[sh]     

    def __iter__(self):
        return (self)

    def __str__(self):
        for value in self.shape_dict.values():
            return "{}".format(value.__str__)


shape_set=ShapeSet()
triangle=Triangle(3,4)
shape_set.addShape(triangle)
print (triangle)
```

Comment: Could you review this and update with a [mcve], correcting indentation and making it clear what output you *get* and what output you *want*.

Comment: `__str__` is a function, not a string itself, you could call `__str__()`, but that's a magic function and is what is invoked if you call `str(value)` instead, generally you don't directly call `__str__`

Comment: This for loop will only look at one `value` because you immediately `return` it... `for value in self.shape_dict.values():`

Comment: Calling `__str__` is usually done by using the builtin `str` function, but your real issue is not having a `__repr__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two mistakes: One is that value.**str** is a function, so you want to call it by adding "()" to it. Secondly, I think you probably want to print all of the shapes in the ShapeSet, correct? In this case, you need to traverse the entire list, and not just return the first shape you find. This seems to work:

```
def __str__(self):
    s = ''
    for key in self.shape_dict.keys():
        s += '\n'.join([value.__str__() for value in self.shape_dict[key]])
    return s
```

Comment: Thanks Adi, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue is that you've defined `__str__` but not `__repr__` in your `Triangle` class. When your `ShapeSet` class tries to output it, it's formatting a `list` of `Triangle` instances. (The `list` may only have one instance in it, but it's still a list.) Python's built-in containers format their contents with `repr` rather than `str` so that things like `["foo, bar", "baz"]` will be unambiguous.

So: try adding `__repr__ = __str__` to your class, and I suspect things will work better!